# openMP chunk size, which should I choose?

Tags: multithreading, matrix, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm making a parallelization with OpenMP for a university project. My problem is the following: I'm making a boolean multiplication of a symmetric matrix with itself, i.e. I need to compute the square of a matrix. I check if the result of the multiplication is equal to the original matrix. I want to know how should I choose the chunk size knowing that the dimension of the matrix can change from small values (like 10) to high ones (for instance 3000). This is the code:

```
bool booleanmult(int dimension,bool** mat,bool** B){

int m,n,k,chunk;
bool temp=false;
bool stop=false;

#pragma omp parallel shared(mat,B,stop,temp) private(m,n,k)

{
        omp_set_num_threads(4);

        chunk=dimension/omp_get_num_threads();
        printf("Chunk size = %d \n",chunk);

    // Boolean Multiplication

    #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic,chunk ) reduction(||:temp)

    for (m=0; m<dimension; m++) {

        for (n=0; n<dimension; n++) {

            for (k=0; k<dimension; k++) {

                temp=mat[m][k] && mat[n][k];
                B[m][n]= B[m][n] || temp;
            }

            if(stop==false && !(B[m][n]==mat[m][n])){
                stop=true;

            }
        }
    }

}
return stop;
}
```

In addition, I would like to if the parallelization done is right, i.e. parallelizing only the most external for. Thank you!!

Comment: The only approach for choosing the chunk size that will definitely work is the empirical approach - try a bunch of chunk sizes and measure the performance.   But for now, there are likely to be more important optimizations than chunk size (and, because the amount of work is so regular across the matrix, dynamic is unlikely to help).  In particular, [loop tiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_tiling) is [quite important for dense matrix multiplication](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~bindel/class/cs5220-s10/slides/lec03.pdf), and even more so for the multithreaded case.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you are using dynamic scheduling with an explicit chunk size. Is this a constraint in your project? If not, try just using static (mostly default) scheduling, and measure its speedup. Then, try out `dynamic` with a couple of chunk numbers. I don't see OpenMP scheduling policies and their parameters would affect your code a lot.

In addition, I don't understand why `temp` is declared with `reduction`. `temp` is reset in every loop iteration (`k`). Reduction is only meaningful when you accumulate results. Hence, first fix your code, then do optimization for better speedup.

Comment: I used dynamic scheduling and results are dramatic. With static scheduling and chunk size 1 by default the time is 300+ seconds whereas with dynamic it is 30.

Answer (score 0):

ı see you are NOT using SPMD pattern why did you used omp_set_num_threads(4), ıf you dont you can get better performance ı think